# How to control mutex lock and unlock?

Tags: c, linux, mutex

I have a question about a basic mutex lock and unlock example!

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define TNUM 4

pthread_mutext_t mutx;
int cnt = 0;


void *t_function(void *data)
{

    while(cnt < 1000)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx);
        cnt++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx);
    }

}

int main()
{
    pthread_t p_thread[TNUM];
    int thr_id[TNUM];
    int status;
    int i;
    clock_t start, end;

    status = pthread_mutex_init(&mutx, NULL);

    start = clock();

    for(i=0; i<TNUM; i++)
    {
        thr_id[i] = pthread_create(&p_thread[i], NULL, t_function, NULL);
        if(thr_id[i] < 0)
        {
            perror("thread create error: ");
            exit(i);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<TNUM; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(p_thread[i], (void**)&status);
    }

    end = clock();

    printf("time : %lf\n", (double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("result : %d\n", cnt);
    return 0;
}
```

When I print the value of 'cnt' after join, it sometimes over 1000 like 1001 or 1002 ....

In my opinion, though a thread make cnt 1000, some other threads already passed the while condition get mutex and the value goes over the maximum(1000).

I think just add inspection code in while loop is bad way.
Is there any better way to fix this problem?

Comment: You post full code. Nothing can be said from the snipped you gave us.

Comment: ^^^ yeah.  If I print the value of 'cnt' after join': what join?

Comment: 'other threads already passed the while condition get mutex' - the mutex is acquired before the while loop, so I don't see how you can get cnt>1000.

Comment: oh sorry plz see the code again. mutex is acquired in the while loop. I edited my code.

Comment: Sorry - you've blown it, close-voting.

Comment: @Pablo the system call initializes it: 'status = pthread_mutex_init(&mutx, NULL);'.

Comment: Grrr: you have `pthread_mutext_t mutx;` — for pity's sake, don't post code with typos that prevent it compiling!  You have one too many t's in there: `pthread_mutex_t mutx;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think that 4 threads are awaiting to acquire the mutex and running simultaneously. When they reach to `while(cnt < 1000)`, they may or may not check `cnt < 1000` condition being subject to OS. Assume that it is satisfied for all of them then now they are inside of `while` and ready to acquire lock and increment count.

```
while(cnt < 1000)
{ 
    // --> assume that all threads are here
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx);
    cnt++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx);
}
```

@Edit

Thanks to @Jonathan Leffler, to get right result, change it like

```
while(cnt < 1000) { 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx); 
    if (cnt < 1000)  
        cnt++; 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx); 
}
```

Comment: The 'proposed solution' with lock before and after the loop means that one thread increments the counter, and the others never get a chance.  Better would be to retest the condition in the loop after the lock and before the increment — `while(cnt < 1000)
{ 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx);
    if (cnt < 1000) cnt++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx);
}`  There is also an argument that you should never access the variable `cnt` without have a mutex lock — it could lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: I want to operate it simultaneously at many threads... Jonathan's comment sounds good

Comment: You should have emphasized on your intend on your question clearly. @신효준

Comment: That is how it was originally.  OP screwed up and transcribed its homework incorrectly:(

Comment: the original code was my type mistake in copying my code sorry@MartinJames

Comment: Mr.Leffler, you said `you should never access the variable cnt without have a mutex lock`. What was the problem related to the prior solution e.g. lock before while and unlock after while other than the `another threads get a chance`? By saying the first quoted one? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: With the lock before the loop and the unlock after the loop, precisely one thread will ever get to increment the count; the other threads will have to wait for that thread to complete, will find that the count is at 1000, and therefore will exit the loop.  This minimizes the concurrency, therefore.  I'm not sure whether to suggest using a function `int get_count(void) { pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx); int cnt_val = cnt; pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx); return cnt_val; }` and use `while (get_count() < 1000)` for the loop control, or something more esoteric _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ One possible more esoteric option would be `int copy_cnt = 0; while (copy_cnt < 1000) { pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx); if (cnt < 1000) cnt++; copy_cnt = cnt; pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx); }`  Both suggestions ensure that `cnt` is only read while the thread has the mutex locked, so no other thread can be modifying it at the same time as the current thread is reading it.

Comment: But the esoteric option stucks, sir. Why do you call that as? **esoteric** @JonathanLeffler

Comment: OK; I'll have to do some testing.  I'm not sure that I see how it gets stuck, but …  I call it esoteric because instead of testing the value of `cnt` directly, the outer loop tests a copy of `cnt`, but is careful (or so I thought) to set the `copy_cnt` only to 0 before the loop or the current value of `cnt` while it has the mutex locked.  And `copy_cnt` does have to be a local variable in the function — not a global variable.  Each thread needs its own copy of `copy_cnt`.

Comment: The 'esoteric' code in the comment has a typo in it — it locks the mutex twice, rather than locking and then unlocking it.

Comment: Now ok, I've just grasped it sir. Thanks @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that contains the code from the question, and from various answers, and from comments I made to one of those answers — plus a test harness.

```
/* SO 4972-0718 */
#include "posixver.h"
#include "stderr.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TNUM 4

static pthread_mutex_t mutx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static int cnt = 0;
static int trace = 0;

/* Code from question */
static void *t_function_0(void *data)
{
    int tid = (uintptr_t)data;
    int inc = 0;
    while (cnt < 1000)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx);
        cnt++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx);
        inc++;
        if (trace) printf("%d\n", tid);
    }
    if (trace) printf("%d done (%d increments)\n", tid, inc);
    return (void *)(uintptr_t)inc;
}

/* Original code from answer by @snr */
static void *t_function_1(void *data)
{
    int tid = (uintptr_t)data;
    int inc = 0;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx);
    while (cnt < 1000)
    {
        cnt++;
        if (trace) printf("%d\n", tid);
        inc++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx);
    if (trace) printf("%d done (%d increments)\n", tid, inc);
    return (void *)(uintptr_t)inc;
}

/* Revised code from answer by @snr */
static void *t_function_2(void *data)
{
    int tid = (uintptr_t)data;
    int inc = 0;
    while (cnt < 1000)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx);
        if (cnt < 1000)
        {
            cnt++;
            inc++;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx);
        if (trace) printf("%d\n", tid);
    }
    if (trace) printf("%d done (%d increments)\n", tid, inc);
    return (void *)(uintptr_t)inc;
}

/* Support function for commentary answer by JL */
static int get_count(void)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx);
    int cnt_val = cnt;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx);
    return cnt_val;
}

/* Code from commentary answer by JL - only reading cnt when mutex is locked */
static void *t_function_3(void *data)
{
    int tid = (uintptr_t)data;
    int inc = 0;
    while (get_count() < 1000)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx);
        if (cnt < 1000)
        {
            cnt++;
            inc++;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx);
        if (trace) printf("%d\n", tid);
    }
    if (trace) printf("%d done (%d increments)\n", tid, inc);
    return (void *)(uintptr_t)inc;
}

/* 'Esoteric' code from commentary answer by JL - only reading cnt when mutex is locked */
static void *t_function_4(void *data)
{
    int tid = (uintptr_t)data;
    int inc = 0;
    int copy_cnt = 0;
    while (copy_cnt < 1000)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx);
        if (cnt < 1000)
        {
            cnt++;
            inc++;
        }
        copy_cnt = cnt;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx);
        if (trace) printf("%d\n", tid);
    }
    if (trace) printf("%d done (%d increments)\n", tid, inc);
    return (void *)(uintptr_t)inc;
}

static const char optstr[] = "t01234";
static const char usestr[] = "[-t01234]";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    static void *(*functions[])(void *) =
    {
        t_function_0, t_function_1, t_function_2,
        t_function_3, t_function_4,
    };
    int variant = 0;
    int opt;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optstr)) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
            variant = opt - '0';
            break;
        case 't':
            trace = 1;
            break;
        default:
            err_usage(usestr);
        }
    }

    printf("Variant %d: ", variant);
    fflush(stdout);

    pthread_t p_thread[TNUM];
    int thr_id[TNUM];

    clock_t start = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < TNUM; i++)
    {
        thr_id[i] = pthread_create(&p_thread[i], NULL, functions[variant], (void *)(uintptr_t)i);
        if (thr_id[i] < 0)
        {
            errno = thr_id[i];
            err_syserr("failed to create thread %d\n", i);
        }
    }

    int inc[TNUM];
    for (int i = 0; i < TNUM; i++)
    {
        void *vp;
        pthread_join(p_thread[i], &vp);
        inc[i] = (int)(uintptr_t)vp;
        if (trace) printf("Join %d: %d increments\n", i, inc[i]);
    }

    clock_t end = clock();

    printf("time : %.6lfs  ", (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("result : %d  ", cnt);
    const char *pad = " [ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < TNUM; i++)
    {
        printf("%s%d", pad, inc[i]);
        pad = ", ";
    }
    printf(" ]\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The code for the error reporting functions such as `err_syserr()` is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

Sample output from running the program 5 times with each of `-0`, `-1`, `-2`, `-3` and `-4`.

```
Variant 0: time : 0.006511s  result : 1003   [ 251, 251, 251, 250 ]
Variant 0: time : 0.007028s  result : 1003   [ 251, 251, 251, 250 ]
Variant 0: time : 0.006156s  result : 1003   [ 333, 224, 223, 223 ]
Variant 0: time : 0.006656s  result : 1003   [ 251, 251, 250, 251 ]
Variant 0: time : 0.006931s  result : 1003   [ 252, 250, 250, 251 ]
Variant 1: time : 0.000462s  result : 1000   [ 0, 0, 1000, 0 ]
Variant 1: time : 0.000345s  result : 1000   [ 1000, 0, 0, 0 ]
Variant 1: time : 0.000345s  result : 1000   [ 1000, 0, 0, 0 ]
Variant 1: time : 0.000388s  result : 1000   [ 1000, 0, 0, 0 ]
Variant 1: time : 0.000340s  result : 1000   [ 1000, 0, 0, 0 ]
Variant 2: time : 0.006203s  result : 1000   [ 251, 250, 249, 250 ]
Variant 2: time : 0.006779s  result : 1000   [ 250, 250, 250, 250 ]
Variant 2: time : 0.006841s  result : 1000   [ 251, 250, 250, 249 ]
Variant 2: time : 0.005960s  result : 1000   [ 251, 250, 250, 249 ]
Variant 2: time : 0.006416s  result : 1000   [ 250, 250, 250, 250 ]
Variant 3: time : 0.012238s  result : 1000   [ 250, 250, 250, 250 ]
Variant 3: time : 0.012763s  result : 1000   [ 250, 250, 250, 250 ]
Variant 3: time : 0.013417s  result : 1000   [ 250, 250, 250, 250 ]
Variant 3: time : 0.012676s  result : 1000   [ 250, 250, 250, 250 ]
Variant 3: time : 0.012899s  result : 1000   [ 250, 250, 250, 250 ]
Variant 4: time : 0.005999s  result : 1000   [ 250, 250, 250, 250 ]
Variant 4: time : 0.006461s  result : 1000   [ 251, 250, 250, 249 ]
Variant 4: time : 0.006112s  result : 1000   [ 250, 250, 250, 250 ]
Variant 4: time : 0.005910s  result : 1000   [ 251, 249, 250, 250 ]
Variant 4: time : 0.006832s  result : 1000   [ 250, 250, 250, 250 ]
```

There are some interesting results in there.  The variant 0 results uniformly show a result larger than 1000, and there's one set where the results are quite skewed instead of almost uniform.  I'm not sure what caused that.  The variant 1 results show emphatically that one thread only gets to increment the counter.  Variants 2, 3, 4 show almost uniform distributions.  The time for variant 3 is about twice that of the others because it does twice as many mutex operations — one pair in the `get_count()` function and one pair in the loop body.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll do tests after understanding your code.:)

Comment: My original question was how to control the variant 0 results of this code(larger than 1000). I think other variants don't give any chance to other threads to increase the cnt @Jonathan Leffler

Comment: The Variant 0 can't be fixed directly — you need to use one of the other variants to ensure that the count does not exceed the limit.  The fact that all the Variant 3 results were uniformly 250, 250, 250, 250 by the 4 threads is coincidence; I just ran another one and got 262, 247, 246, 245 (but the total is exactly 1000, as with each variant except Variant 0).  In my testing, of a sequence of 30 runs of Variant 3, only 5 had non-uniform distributions.

Comment: Or, alternatively, there are at least 4 different ways to fix Variant 0 — those ways are Variants 1-4.  Of those, Variants 3 and 4 are the most satisfactory because the `cnt` variable is never accessed — for reading or writing — unless the thread holds the mutex so no other thread can be accessing it at the same time (and hence possibly modifying it at the same time).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm here after a while on the same question. You are locking mutex in `get_count()` method but at the same time(possibly) in `t_function_3()` you are trying to acquire lock by calling `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx);` via the same thread. Isn't it undefined behavior or error?

Comment: @snr: I'm not sure what you mean.  Within a single thread, `get_count()` operates synchronously with the direct calls to `pthread_mutex_lock()`, so there is no simultaneity in a single thread.  And with multiple threads all running in their own copy of the same function, there is no conflict — the whole point of mutexes is to allow parallel running threads to work and synchronize safely.  You may need to explain your request more — consider using email (see my profile; include "Stack Overflow" in the subject line and a link to this question in the body, please).

Answer (score 0):

Use **pthread mutexes** to do atomic action(only one operation at a time on same variable). when a `mutex` is locked by `one thread`, all other lock requests from `other thread` will block the `thread(which took the lock)`, unlock itself after finishing all its operations.

Here is the sample `t_function()`

```
void *t_function(void *data) {
        printf(" %s is doing something \n",__func__);
        while(1) {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx);
                if(cnt == 1000) {
                        printf("ready ..other can do \n");
                        break;
                }
                cnt++;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx);
                printf("waiting for cnt to reach 1000\n");
        }
        pthread_exit(0);
}
```

but here `while(1)` is **Busy Wait** consumes a lot of CPU cycles as it does not move out of processor till its time slice expires.

So instead of this, use a **pthread condition variable** to save CPU cycles.

Comment: Note that the `break;` leaves the mutex locked.  That's not good!  (Tangentially and trivially: the space before the `++` is not a good idea.)

Comment: thanks. It seems pthread condition variable is good way to fix this problem..

Comment: ya I'm thinking same @JonathanLeffler what I can suggest instead of `break`.

Comment: What?  None of what you have posted makes any sense.

Comment: You can add `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx);` before the break — that's simplest, but does involve some code repetition.